# IIS Cannot find web.config when publishing a .netcore with only .net46

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I publish to azure my .net46 MVC project which was built using the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template i get a HSC500 error. When viewing the streaming logs I can see the message:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

my project.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "5.0.2",
    "AutoMapper.EF6": "0.5.0",
    "BlueStar.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "BlueStar.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "BlueStar.Data.EntityFramework": "1.0.0-*",
    "BlueStar.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "EntityFramework.Extended": "6.1.0.168",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
    },

    "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the web.config exists in the correct location on Azure?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?